# Can you specify git-shell in .ssh/authorized_keys to restrict access to only git commands via ssh?

Tags: ssh, git

I'd like to be able to use a ssh key for authentication, but still restrict the commands that can be executed over the ssh tunnel.

With Subversion, I've achieved this by using a .ssh/authorized_keys file like:

```
command="/usr/local/bin/svnserve -t --tunnel-user matt -r /path/to/repository",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIetc...
```

I've tried this with "/usr/bin/git-shell" in the command, but I just get the funky old `fatal: What do you think I am? A shell?` error message.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The following works for me.

In `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

```
command="./gitserve",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-dss AAAAB…
```

In the `~/gitserve` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec git-shell -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
```

Note that if you put `gitserve` somewhere other than the home directory, you will have to adjust the `command="./gitserve"` parameter in `authorized_keys`.

Comment: Bingo! This is works just like what I was hoping to achieve! Thanks.

Comment: In this related post on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871652/running-a-secure-git-server-over-ssh-without-gitosis-gitolite they point to another solution here: http://joey.kitenet.net/blog/entry/locking_down_ssh_authorized_keys/

Comment: @Tim This is essentially the same solution, but squeezes the content of my ~/gitserve script into authorized keys by using perl. Personally, I prefer keeping it in a separate script.

Comment: I understand, I merely added it as reference.

Comment: What shell do you have the user set to in this configuration? `/bin/bash`?

Comment: @Qwertman, it doesn't matter. All the shell has to do is execute `./gitserve`. In my system I do have it set to `/bin/bash`. If you're using `/bin/true` for security, however, it's not going to work. It must be set to a real shell.

Comment: I'm wondering why it doesn't work with the [restrict](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Client_Configuration_Files#restrict) option. It's shorter and I usually prefer a whitelist to a blacklist but apparently `restrict` is more restrictive than the options of this answer. Does anyone know more?

Answer (score 43):

I could successfully use git-shell directly in the authorizedKeys file without using an additionnal script.

The key is to add `\"` around the env variable.

Tested in rhel6 openssh-server-5.3p1-70.el6.x86_64:

```
no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,command="git-shell -c \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\"" ssh-dss AAAA...
```

Comment: +1 that's the correct answer, see http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/crypto/openssh/auth-options.c?revision=261320&view=markup#l154

Comment: Personally, I'd give the full path to `git-shell`, but that might just be paranoia.

Comment: Has anyone found a way of restricting the directory to which it has access? I found that i can cd into a directory before executing git-shell, but git-shell allows ".." and absolute paths.

Answer (score 5):

[Grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity)'s solution can be easily modified to work by replacing the line

```
        exec $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

with the line

```
        git-shell -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
```

The quotes take care of the issues reported above, and replacing exec with git-shell seems a bit more secure.

Answer (score 4):

`git-shell` is designed to be used as a login shell, so that it would receive `-c "originalcommand"` as arguments. This doesn't happen with "forced commands" in OpenSSH; instead, the *forced command* is passed to the configured shell.

What you can do is write a script that checks `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` and executes it. Example in *bash*:

```
#!/bin/bash

SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND=${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND/#git /git-}

case $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in
    "git-receive-pack"*|"git-upload-pack"*|"git-upload-archive"*)
        eval exec $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Go away." >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: @Matt: [git-shell(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shell.html) says the commands are `git <cmd>`, not `git-<cmd>`?

Comment: Hmm... I made that change according to what I saw when I ran it. With both a bash script and a ruby script, I saw "git-receive-pack" as the command. Quote from my `man git-shell` (git 1.7.3.4):

       Currently, only four commands are permitted to be called, git-receive-pack git-upload-pack and
       git-upload-archive with a single required argument, or cvs server (to invoke git-cvsserver).

Comment: formatting doesn't work in comments :(

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because my git client (1.7.5.4) sends the repo name in single quotes, presumably because it's expecting to have the entire command line interpreted by a shell. The exec $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND then passes the single quotes on to git-receive-pack etc. which therefore doesn't find the repository.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, grawity, but it doesn't work for me, for the same reason that was reported by Neil Mayhew... my 1.7.x version of git also sends the repo name in single quotes, ultimately causing the `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` to be invalid, and causing `git-shell` to bum out :-(

Comment: Added `eval` to fix the quote issue.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, and since the original question didn't specify that the same account had to be useable for non-git things, the obvious answer is to use `git-shell` as it was designed to be used: set it as the login shell (i.e. with `usermod`, in `/etc/passwd`) for that ssh user.

If you do have a single user account that you want to use two ways:

- when connecting with key authentication, use only for git
- when connecting with password authentication, or using a different private key, provide a full shell

...then the other answers in this thread apply. But if you can afford to allocate a separate user to git, then setting its shell to `git-shell` is the simplest way to restrict it, and is slightly more secure as it requires no additional shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get [grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity)'s solution to work for the same reason that was reported by [Neil Mayhew](https://superuser.com/users/41709/neil-mayhew) (ie. the single quotes sent by the git client causing an invalid `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` -- I'm using `git v1.7.x`)

However, the following solution implemented by [@moocode](https://moocode.com/posts/6-code-your-own-multi-user-private-git-server-in-5-minutes) just works:

https://moocode.com/posts/6-code-your-own-multi-user-private-git-server-in-5-minutes

Ruby FTW!  :-)